# Correct way to choose a file for open

Tags: android, file, uri, filechooser

I am using this intent to open a chooser to pick up a file:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(getExternalFilesDir(null).toString()), "*/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose File");
startActivityForResult(chooser, FILE_SELECT);
```

I don't fully understand it, but it works. I copied it from some example in the web
The result is an uri, but I find the processing of the uri, also copied from the example, too cumbersome

```
if(uri != null) {
    if("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        String[] projection = {"_data"};
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_data");
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    } else if("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }
}
```

**Is this the simplest way to let the user pick a file and get its path?**
Why do I need to check if the uri is "content"? I just want to open a text or zipped file the user chose in the intent.
Can I ignore the "content" check, just assume "file" and simply use `uri.getPath()` ?

Edit I: Is there a way to force choosing with uri scheme "file"?

Comment: Very important. had the same question.
And while still on the topic, I really cant understand, what is the reason for " return cursor.getString(column_index);" ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is correct. You are basically starting an intent to get access to the native app. which in this case is the file system. The next would be a part of the onActivityResultData() which would then use the uri on the intent and get the contents of the file that has been selected.

Comment: @Iokoko I added my comment into the question.

Comment: This would just return the scheme. Something like http. So here you are checking if the scheme is content which it is for files.

Comment: @Iokoko I know what the code is doing, and I know it works OK. I am looking to simplifiy it. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: This is simple in itself :)

Comment: @Iokoko :-) You are right, but IMHO these are too many lines just to pick up a file.

Comment: @Iokoko I usually wait 48hrs before I mark an answer. Let's give the gurus the chance to top you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if Android isn't trying to push us away from file paths and towards Uris. Try something like:

```
InputStream inputStream=contentResolver.openInputStream(uri);
InputStreamReader file = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
int size = file.read(text,0,mMaxLen);
```